Starter Bootstrap and Custom Fonts
I'm building a custom theme using https://them.es/starter-bootstrap I have some custom fonts in the /assets folder and some Sass generated by http://font.download The custom fonts seem to be included in the compiled CSS but the font files aren't being copied over. This is the error from my developer toolbar:
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Museo 300" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://example.local/wp-content/themes/example-theme/build/fonts/Museo300-Regular.0c331dbb.woff
For development, I'm running npm run watch Why isn't the font copied to /build/fonts?
Thanks in advance!

Hello and welcome to StackExchange for WordPress.
When you run npm run watch it only watches the compiling process of your .sass files, It's not magically recognizing the things you want.
You have to explicitly tell your bundler to do that.
You could manually put all the fonts in their respective, correct place.
However, that is not always desirable.
I've had a quick look at the link, which you have given and that theme is using webpack for asset compilation. So, in order to move your fonts around correctly, you need to expand of Webpack's configuration to do that.
To bring you one step forward to a solution, you should go to the Webpack docs and dig into the loaders section, which is what you want I think:
Webpack CSS Loader
